# Is this application of Brouwer fixed point theorem correct?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

I recently read a paper using Brouwer fixed point theorem in finite dimensional Hilbert space as follows:

$X$ is a finite dimensional Hilbert space with inner product $(.,.)$ and norm $||.||$. $f:X \to X$ is continuous. If $f$ satisfies that: For a positive constant $C$, the result $(f(x),x) {\ge} 0$ always holds for all $x\in X$ with $||x||=C$. Then, there exists $x_0\in X$ with $||x_0||\le C$, such that, $f(x_0)=0$.

I want to know if this is true. If it is true, can you show me some reference about it?( Not just reference who cite it, but about prove it)

Comment: This feels really similar to the proof from Milnor of the Brouwer fixed point theorem, given the Hairy Ball theorem. There is a moment where he has a nonzero continuous vector field which points outward on the boundary and then he deduces a contradiction. I can't quite make the details fit with your situation, though

Comment: Good idea, I followed that paper and proof. It is applicable actually.

Comment: How did you adapt the proof idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is true. You can get this result from the Leray-Schauder Alternative (which also delivers Brouwer's fixed point theorem). Reduced to your situation ($B(0,C)$ a closed ball in a finite dimensional vector space $X$) the Leray-Schauder Alternative reads:

If $F:B(0,C) \to X$ is continuous, then (at least) one of the following two assertions hold:

1. $F$ has a fixed point.
2. There exist $x \in \partial B(0,C)$ and $\lambda \in (0,1)$ such that $x=\lambda F(x)$.

Application to $F:B(0,C) \to X$, $F(x)=x-f(x)$ leads to the following contradiction if you assume that $F$ has no fixed point (that is, if you assume that $f$ has no zero in $B(0,C)$): There exist $x \in \partial B(0,C)$ and $\lambda \in (0,1)$ such that $x= \lambda (x- f(x))$. Then
$(1-\lambda)x = - \lambda f(x)$, hence
$$
0<(1-\lambda)C^2= (1-\lambda) \|x\|^2 = - \lambda \langle f(x),x \rangle \le 0.
$$
Note that the  Leray-Schauder Alternative is far from trivial even in this reduced version. You can find it (with proof) for example in the following books:

Dugundji J., Granas A.: Fixed Point Theory, Springer (2003), p.123

Agarwal R.P., Meehan M., ORegan D.: Fixed Point Theory and Applications, CUP (2004), Theorem 5.1

Comment: Thank your for your help!!!!